# Generating dataContext cs file for sharepoint 2010 site collection

Tags: 2010, listdata.svc

We have a service to run and return queries from a SharePoint 2010 site collection.  At its core is a cs file that contains the DataContext info for the site, all the lists, etc.

I want to re-use the code to make similar queries for another site collection (with different lists, of course) on the same web. Problem is, nobody can remember from which service or data the file was generated. The original coder is all but sure it was indeed generated with svcutil, but the trail runs dry after that. sites, search and sitedata all return different results.

A brief snippet of the file is posted below in the hopes that someone might recognize it.

```
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// <auto-generated>
//     This code was generated by a tool.
//     Runtime Version:2.0.50727.5485
//
//     Changes to this file may cause incorrect behavior and will be lost if
//     the code is regenerated.
// </auto-generated>
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------

// Original file name: SharePointRest.cs
// Generation date: 11/10/2014 11:18:30 AM
namespace Microsoft.SharePoint.DataService.Financial
{

/// <summary>
/// There are no comments for FinancialDataContext in the schema.
/// </summary>
public partial class FinancialDataContext : global::System.Data.Services.Client.DataServiceContext
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Initialize a new FinancialDataContext object.
    /// </summary>
    [System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.Data.Services.Design", "1.0.0")]
    public FinancialDataContext(global::System.Uri serviceRoot) : 
            base(serviceRoot)
    {
        this.OnContextCreated();
    }
    partial void OnContextCreated();
    /// <summary>
    /// There are no comments for Attachments in the schema.
    /// </summary>
    [System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.Data.Services.Design", "1.0.0")]
    public global::System.Data.Services.Client.DataServiceQuery<AttachmentsItem> Attachments
    {
        get
        {
            if ((this._Attachments == null))
            {
                this._Attachments = base.CreateQuery<AttachmentsItem>("Attachments");
            }
            return this._Attachments;
        }
    }
```

I'm absolutely sure there are a hundred better ways to access and return the data from the site in question, but there are no resources to build something new, so the best plan is to find out how to generate this data for the other site.

Comment: Based on the code, the "SharePointRest.cs" is an indicator that it's using REST to reach the SharePoint data, and this snippet isn't what you are looking for, but is there any source code? I'm sure there may be some 3rd party tool at play here. This looks relevant: http://wp.sjkp.dk/generate-c-classes-for-sharepoint-rest-api/

Comment: That's not impossible, though the original coder doesn't remember any third party tools being used, and I can run the code with no extra installs. Technically, the code I posted IS what I'm looking for, or more precisely, how to generate a version of it for the new site on which I want to use the code. I have all the source code, it's just this site-specific file I'm looking to generate.